# Keras Dense Net Overfitting

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, classification

I am attempting to use keras to build an activity classifier from accelerometer signals. However, I am experiencing extreme overfitting of the data even with the most simplistic of models.

The input data is of shape (10,3) and contains roughly .1 second of data from the accelerometer in 3 dimensions. The model is simply

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(10,3)))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The model should output the label [1,0] for walking activities and [0,1] for non-walking activities. After training I get 99.8% accuracy (if only it was real...). When I attempt to predict on data that wasn't used for training, I get 50% accuracy, verifying that the net isn't really "learning" anything except to predict a single class value.

The data is being prepared from 100hz triaxial accelerometer signals. I am not preprocessing the data in any way except for windowing it into bins on length 10 that overlap with the previous bin by 50%. What measures can I take to make the network produce actual predictions? I have tried increasing the window size but the results remain the same. Any advice/general tips are greatly appreciated.

Ian

Comment: How many training examples you have? Do you use cross-validation when fitting the model? Are your classes biased or skewed in some way? Do you stratify your train/test set? Usually you would use regularization (l1, l2, dropout etc..) to control the overfitting but with a model that small (and still overfitting), it wouldn't make a difference. I feel like there is another problem with the data. Have you tried simpler models like logistic regression, random forests etc..?

Comment: @umutto there are roughly 25k training examples and am using a validation split of .25. I have used dropout in some of the more complex models that I have created but purposefully left it out here in the name of simplicity. I am going to play with the random forest approach now and will update with any new information.

Comment: I don't think dropout would do anything in here anyways (you only have 2 units). Yup, you should try random forests and see if it gives better results. If not, than probably there is some structural problem with your dataset or train/test split. 25k and using validation sounds good to me, it even sounds like you should have a leeway for using much more complex models with regularization, overfitting in here sounds like a skewed data and an unlucky train/test split.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some hidden layers and dropout layers to your network. You could create a simple [Multi Layer Perceptron (MLP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayer_perceptron) with a couple of extra lines in between your Flatten layer and Dense layer:

```
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=30))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
```

[Or check out this guide.](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/) which explains how to create a simple MLP.

Without any hidden layers your model will not actually be 'learning' from the input data, rather it will be mapping the input number of features to the output number of features.

The more layers you add, the more intermediate features and patterns it should extract from the input data which should lead to better model predictions for test data. There will be a lot of trial and error to design the best model as too many layers can result in over fitting.

You have not provided information about how you train the model so that may be the cause of the issue as well. You must ensure that the data is spit into training, testing and validation sets. Some possible split ratios to use for training, validation, test data are: 60%:20%:20%, or 70%:15%:15%. This is ultimately something that you must also decide.

Comment: To answer your question about training, validation, and test, there are roughly 25K samples. I am saving 10% of the samples for validation and have another set of 2500 samples for test. I would rather not add additional layers at this point, all I am trying to demonstrate is that the model is not being overfit to the data. From there I will move back to the real model that I was attempting to use and see if I can resolve the overfitting problems there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of overfitting was caused by the input data type. The values passed to the classifier should have been float values with 2 decimal places. Somewhere along the way, some of these values had been augmented and had significantly more than 2 decimal places. That is, the input should have looked like

```
[9.81, 10.22, 11.3]
```

but instead looked like

```
[9.81000000012, 10.220010431, 11.3000000101]
```

The classifier was making its prediction based on this feature, which is obviously not the desired behavior! Lessoned learned - make sure the data preparation is consistent! Thanks to @umutto for the suggestions of random forests, the simple structure was helpful for diagnosing purposes.